# Multiple composition to extend interface features

Tags: python, inheritance, interface, software-design, composition

I have an interface that defines some core API, like so:

```py
class CoreInterface:
    def core_func(self):
        pass
```

I also have some interfaces that add additional API to the core, like so:

```py
class B_Interface(CoreInterface):
    def b_func(self, *args):
        pass

class C_Interface(CoreInterface):
    def c_func_1(self):
        pass

    def c_func_2(self):
        pass
```

Finally I have a class that implements these interfaces, like so:

```py
class MyClass(B_Interface, C_Interface):
    def core_func(self):
        return 'core_func'
    
    def b_func(self, *args):
        return 'b_func'
    
    def c_func_1(self):
        return 'c_func_1'
    
    def c_func_2(self):
        return 'c_func_2'
```

Pretty straightforward so far.

Now, I want to add some features with composition because I don't want to run into the diamond problem in multiple-inheritance. So I create wrappers for the B and C interface, like so:

```py
class B_Interface_Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    
    def core_func(self):
        retval = self.obj.core_func()
        modified_retval = self.obj.b_func(retval)
        return modified_retval
    
class C_Interface_Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    
    def core_func(self):
        retval = self.obj.core_func()
        retval1 = self.obj.c_func_1()
        retval2 = self.obj.c_func_2()
        return retval, retval1, retval2
```

Individually, it all works as expected. I can wrap MyClass objects with either the B-Wrapper or the C-Wrapper and things go as expected. However, now I want an object with both of the features from B and C, so I wrap both and get the following error:

```
>>> bc_obj = B_Interface_Wrapper(C_Interface_Wrapper(obj))
>>> bc_obj.core_func()

  File "test_script.py", line 61, in <module>
    bc_obj.core_func()
  File "test_script.py", line 25, in core_func
    modified_retval = self.obj.b_func(retval)
AttributeError: 'C_Interface_Wrapper' object has no attribute 'b_func'
```

and similarly if I attempt to wrap it the other way

```
>>> bc_obj = C_Interface_Wrapper(B_Interface_Wrapper(obj))
>>> bc_obj.core_func()

  File "test_script.py", line 62, in <module>
    bc_obj.core_func()
  File "test_script.py", line 34, in core_func
    retval1 = self.obj.c_func_1()
AttributeError: 'B_Interface_Wrapper' object has no attribute 'c_func_1'
```

I can see why this error occurs, but I'm stuck with the design challenge. There are some workarounds that I think are a little hackish, so I'm wondering if my design is fundamentally flawed. Is it bad practice to use composition to extend/modify capabilities like this?